Proving differentiability by testing continuity of the partials?
This is question 54 from Section 2.3 of Susan Jane Colley's Vector Calculus. I need to determine whether the function is differentiable at the point $(a,b) = (1, 0)$
$$
f(x,y) = \big((x-1)y\big)^{2/3}
$$
So my attempt at this began with checking the partial derivatives for continuity. If the partial derivatives are not continuous then $f$ fails to be differentiable.
$$
f_x(x, y) = \frac{2y}{3\big((x-1)y \big)^{1/3}}\\\\
f_y(x, y) = \frac{2(x-1)}{3\big((x-1)y \big)^{1/3}}
$$
Given the both partials are not defined at $(a,b) = (1,0)$, then I determined $f$ is not differentiable. However, I took a look at the solution manual it asserts that the function is indeed differentiable. I have provided her proof of this below.
Solutions
The solution manual asserts that
$$
f(x,0) \equiv 0 \Rightarrow f_x(1, 0) = 0\\\\
f(1,y) \equiv 0 \Rightarrow f_y(1, 0) = 0
$$
The tangent plane $h(x, y) = f(1,0) + f_x(1, 0)(x-1) + f_y(1, 0)(y-0) = 0$. Thus, for $(x,y) \neq (1,0)$ we have that
$$
0 \leq \frac{|f(x,y) - h(x,y)|}{||(x,y) - (1,0)||} = \frac{|f(x,y)|}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2}}
$$
Then
$$
|f(x,y)| = |x-1|^{2/3}|y|^{2/3} \leq ((x-1)^2 + y^2)^{1/3}((x-1)^2 + y^2)^{1/3}\\\\
= ((x-1)^2 + y^2)^{2/3}
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{|f(x,y)|}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2}} \leq \frac{((x-1)^2 + y^2)^{2/3}}{((x-1)^2 + y^2)^{1/2}} = ((x-1)^2 + y^2)^{1/6}
$$
Because the last expression approaches zero as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ then $f$ must be differentiable at $(1,0)$
I have several questions

Could you explain why despite the fact the partial derivatives are not continuous at $(a,b) = (1,0)$, we go on to assert differentiability?
Why does $f(x,0) \equiv 0$ mean that $f_x(1, 0) = 0$?
The argument on the tangent plane is confusing. We say $h(1,0) = 0$ but the proof goes on to say "For $(x,y) \neq (1,0)$" and then proceeds to use $h(x)$ at $(1,0)$
In the line beginning $|f(x,y)$, what identity is this being used?
In the final argument, is this some variation of the squeeze theorem in that if $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,0)}((x-1)^2 + y^2)^{1/6} = 0$ then since this is greater than or equal to $|f(x,y)| = |x-1|^{2/3}|y|^{2/3}$, then its limit must also be zero?

Apologies for the long question but I want to ensure I understand this.

As one of the answers below reminds you, differentiability is not equivalent to the continuity of partial derivatives. Failure of the partial derivatives to be continuous does not necessarily imply that the function is not differentiable.

$f(x,y)=\big((x-1)y\big)^{\frac{2}{3}}$
$1:$ To check the continuity at $(1,0)$, we can just check the definition.
$\textbf{Note}:$ It is true that if a function has continuous partial derivatives at $(1,0)$, then $f$ must be continuous at that $(1,0)$. But the inverse is not true. You can not claim that since partial derivatives are not continuous, then $f$ must not be continuous at that point, the converse is wrong. $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (1,0)}f(x,y)=\lim\limits_{(t,y)\to(0,0)}(ty)^{\frac{2}{3}}=0=f(1,0)$$
Here I used that $t=x-1.$ Thus, it is continuous at $(1,0)$.
$2:$ Also, check the definition:$$f_x(1,0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x,0)-f(1,0)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{0-0}{x}=0$$
Similar for $f_y(1,0).$
$3:$ Here I think it used the Taylor expansion of $f(x,y)$ at the point $(1,0)$, it is valid. $$f(x,y)=f(1,0)+f_x(1,0)(x-1)+f_y(1,0)(y-0)+o \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}$$
We do not need to consider more terms since $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (1,0)}\frac{o \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}=0$$
$4:$ $(ab)^n\leq (a^2+b^2)^n$, because $a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$.
$5:$ Just notice that the lower bound for that is $0$.
$\textbf{Edit:}$
If I do this, I will just check the definition:$$f'(1,0)=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (1,0)}\frac{|f(x,y)-f(1,0)|}{|(x,y)-(1,0)|}=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (1,0)}\frac{|f(x,y)|}{|(x,y)-(1,0)|}$$

Thank you. I was unaware that the converse was not true. 2. Makes sense now thank you. I was not aware that it was her solution was implying. 3. I still do not quite see this - where has $h(x,y)$ gone in this line $|f(x,y) - h(x,y)| = |f(x,y)|$. Would you mind showing this please? 4. Got it that makes perfect sense. 5. This makes sense as well, thank you.

@InvestingScientist See the formula on the fifth row from the bottom to get what is $o$.

@InvestingScientist Provide another way to do it in the final line, without the tangent plane (I have never used it before), just check the definition.

Thank you. The comment you made in your edit that for any point near $(1,0)$, it is still $0$. How is this? If we take $(0.9, 0.1)$ it is small but it is not zero since $f(0.9, 0.1) \neq 0$. What am I missing?

@InvestingScientist Emm... Right. I made a mistake here, so I don't really like this method, I can only explain it using Taylor expansion for $f(x,y)$. Check the definition is always efficient.

Regarding 3, I don't think you can use Taylor's theorem (the bound on the error term) without assuming differentiability.

@MatthewLeingang I cannot find a better way to explain, could you help me?

@BoweiTang I wrote an answer using the author's definition

Most of the answers to your many questions are already very good. I just want to add one point on the third question.
The author is using this definition of differentiable: $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ if $f_x(a,b)$ and $f_y(a,b)$ exist, and furthermore that $$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} \frac{f(x,y) - h(x,y)}{\Vert \left<x,y\right> - \left<a,b\right>\Vert} = 0$$
Here $h(x,y)$ is the linearization of $f$ at $(a,b)$: $h(x,y) = f(a,b)+f_x(a,b)(x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b)$. The graph of $h$ is a plane and is the best candidate for “tangent plane” to the graph of $f$ at $(a,b)$. Every definition of differentiability comes down to the idea that this plane approximates $f(x,y)$ very well near $(a,b)$. How well? Near $(a,b)$ the difference between $f(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$ is much smaller than the distance between $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$.
We are focusing on the point with $a=1$ and $b=0$. Having used the limit definition of partial derivative, we know $f_x(1,0) = f_y(1,0) = 0$. This means $h(x,y) = 0(x-1) + 1(y-0) = 0$. This means we need to check if
$$
    \frac{f(x,y) - h(x,y)}{\Vert \left<x,y\right> - \left<1,0\right>\Vert} = \frac{f(x,y) - 0}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-0)^2}}
= \frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2}}
= \frac{((x-1)y)^{2/3}}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2}}
$$
tends to zero as $(x,y) \to (1,0)$.

Get your idea. Thank you,

Thank you Matthew. I think I see it now - we know $h(x,y) = 0$ because it is defined $h(x) = f(a,b) + f_x(a,b)(x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b) = 0 + 0 + 0 = 0$. Apologies as this does follow from the definition. Thank you very much!

No need to apologize—it takes a minute to understand what a definition says.


You showed that the partials are not continuous at 0, but it is still possible for the partials to exists at $0$. Continuity of the partials implies differentiability, but differentiability does not imply continuity of the partials. So if the partials aren't continuous at $0$, then you need to check differentiability "manually".

Use the definition of $f_x$.

The book's approach is correct. Differentiability at $(1, 0)$ is equivalent to the statement that $f(x, y) - h(x, y) = o(|(x - 1, y - 0)|)$ as $(x, y) \to (1, 0)$. I can rewrite the proof in the way I would do it: Write the remainder as
$$f(1 + h, y) - f(1, 0) = (hy)^{2/3} = |hy|^{2/3}.$$
Then since
$$|hy|^{2/3} \leq (|(h, y)|^2)^{2/3} = |(h, y)|^{4/3} = o(|(h, y)|),$$
we have $f(1 + h, y) = o(|(h, y)|)$, hence we have differentiability at $(1, 0)$ with $Df(1, 0) = 0$.



Thank you. On point 3. what  does the $o$ operator mean?

$g(h, y) = o(q(h, y))$ as $(h, y) \to 0$ means $\lim_{(h, y) \to 0}\frac{g(h, y)}{q(h, y)} = 0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation.
